# How to convert an Xcode project into a static library or framework?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, frameworks, static-libraries

I have a project which I need to import into other project as a framework just like how we import Coredata framework, Quartzcore etc..How to achieve that ? How to compile my project into a library or framework which can be imported into other projects ? Please explain the steps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework try this link for creation of framework and bundle of resources.wrap up the images, xibs and other resources you have used in your project into a bunble and copy your classes to your Cocoa Touch Static Library project.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compile a 'standard' framework like UIKit.framework, try this [Universal Framework iPhone iOS](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/)

else

1. Create a new Project named 'TestPlugin' and choose type "Cocoa touch Static Library". Here you will have a target 'TestPlugin.a'.
2. Add a new target. In left corner of project's setting, the name is:'Add Target'. Choose 'Bundle' in 'Framework and Library' in 'OS X'. This your second target named 'TestPluginBundle.bundle'.
3. In your TestPlugin.a target's 'Build Phrases' setting, add a new 'Target Denpendencies'. This will firstly generate the .bundle file and then the .a file.
4. Copy and add all your 'Original' project's file(exclude the main.m and the .xcodeproj file) to TestPlugin project.
5. In TestPluginBundle's 'Build Phases' setting, add all .xib .png(maybe .jpg) file to 'Compile Sources'. Add spacial resource(such as .wav, .gif and .html) to 'Copy Bundle Resources'.
6. Replace all code that load resource from main bundle to load resource from TestPluginBundle. Maybe you want to add a category for UIImage because you want to use `imageNamed:` so that you can use `[UIImage testPluginImageNamed:@"small.png"]`. It's easy to do replace in your project and add the related header file. Take .xib file For example:

   ```
   - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
   {
       //self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
       // you need to define a method to get the bundle 'TestPluginBundle.bundle', here I used '[TestPlugin TestPluginBundle]'
       self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:[TestPlugin TestPluginBundle]];
       ...
   }
   ```
7. After this add the .a file and .bundle file to another project. In the another project you need to add the related framework again.

I've successfully used this method for my work.

Comment: Could you please explain how to build the framework finally after doing all the above steps ?

Comment: i meant like the one we generally include in xcode projects..predefined frameworks like coredata, quartzcore etc.. how to build such a framework ?

Comment: Is it possible to read the contents of a .a framework? I recently found one .a framework but I have no idea how to use it. Like, what methods are in there for me to use and there are very little assistance on it too. No documentaries on the .a framework either, so I am really stuck.

Comment: @MelvinLai, I don't know ways to read the contents. I just encountered situation that I have the header files of the .a library(this is called the static library). Do you have this?

Comment: @sunkehappy Sorry, I haven't logged into this site for a long time... I got a bit of info regards to my .a file and I am not using it because it is a 3rd party API that Apple will disapprove if I use it. So I am not using it anymore.  OK, now regards to the .a file I do not see any static library at all its just a .a file. I can't see any header files I can't see the contents within the .a file. It is unreliable. So I shoved it aside. Thanks for your reply though :)