# How to convert an iOS project to a Framework

Tags: ios, swift

I want to convert my iOS project into a framework. I already going throw some solutions but can figure it out because those are not descriptive as much. Can anyone help me? Here are the solutions that I already tried:
(1) [Convert Existing iOS App to framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922693/convert-existing-ios-app-to-framework)
(2) [how can i create a framework from existing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925274/how-can-i-create-a-framework-from-existing-project)
(3) [Convert Existing iOS App to framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922693/convert-existing-ios-app-to-framework)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191193/how-to-convert-an-xcode-project-into-a-static-library-or-framework
Have you tried this? Try finding articles of how to do this. The links that you have given, none of them even have an answer. Explain in your question, what have you tried, and then what is the problem you are facing. the question right now is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

File -> New -> Target -> FrameWork -> Make sure its in your app bundle. 
Then in your project you need to make a class where your rootviewController will open.
Then you have to add your project storyboard to that target. and your controllers.

Comment: I follow your procedure and when I build the project it saying multiple commands produce in my project directory. It actually generating duplicate output files in my directory.

Comment: I have updated my ans can you see the image your structure looks same of framework ? and once clean the project

Comment: Yes, the structure is similar to it but the problem remains the same.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a New Framework Target:

Open your Xcode project.
Navigate to File > New > Target.
Choose iOS > Framework as the target type.
Give your framework a descriptive name.
Make sure the framework is part of your app bundle by selecting your project under the Destination option.
2. Move Relevant Code and Resources:

Identify the code and resources you want to expose in your framework (classes, protocols, images, etc.).
Move these files and folders to the new framework target.
3. Configure Framework Target Settings:

In your framework target settings, navigate to Build Settings.
Search for "Packaging" and set Defines Module to Yes. This creates a module map that defines what code is accessible from your framework.
You can also exclude unnecessary files using the Excluded Build Files setting.
4. Define Public Interface (Optional):

If you want to control what code is exposed, create a public header file (.h) in your framework.
In this header, declare the classes, protocols, and functions you want to make accessible.
5. Build and Test the Framework:

Build your project. This should create a framework file (.framework) in your project's derived data folder.
You can create a separate test target for your framework to ensure it functions as expected.